# What is the given value to insert in configuration.php file to function well

Tags: php

Can someone help proper solution to the question. It kind of confusing.

Pls give me value where necessary, it is in the configuration.php file settings

```
<?php
/*
 * ---------------------------------------------------------------
 * SITE PATH
 * ---------------------------------------------------------------
 */

$serverName = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
$sitePath = "http://" . $serverName;
$docRoot = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];

/*
 * -----------------------------------------------------------------
 * END SITE PATH
 * ---------------------------------------------------------------
 */
```

Kindly help to fix the value at the appropriate place.

Comment: There is nothing to configure here. This code initializes the variables `$serverName` with the hostname part of the URL (e.g. `www.example.org`), `$sitePath` with the URL of the site (`http://www.example.org`) and `$docRoot` with the directory on the server where the files of the site are located (e.g. `/var/www/htdocs`; it depends a lot on how the web server is configured). It uses information provided by `PHP` (which knows that information from the web server).

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
<?php

define('ROOT', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . DS );
define('HTTP_SERVER', 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . DS);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much brother.
After inserting the code, this is what i get,

Warning: session_start(): Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already
 sent (output started at /home/humanity/public_html/donation/index.php:4) in /home/humanity/public_html/donation/includes/validation_php.php on line 2

Note: on the /donation/index.php on line four I have this code below

```
<head>


      <?php include 'configuration.php'; ?>
```

While on the donation/includes/validation_php.php  , I have this code

session_start();

include 'configuration.php';

============================================
what i mean is that do i need to insert any value here as given or it should be left the way it is in configuration.php file. I think i need to supply my server details as follows.

$serverName = $_SERVER['www.domain.com'];

$sitePath = "http://" . $serverName;

$docRoot = $_SERVER['/domainpath'];

or will i leave it as it is ..

$serverName = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];

$sitePath = "http://" . $serverName;

$docRoot = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];